# how to rename a folder in Google-storage programmatically?

Tags: java, file, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have a google-storage java client.

I want to rename a folder on the cloud.

It there a way to do it?

I saw the [update post](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/update) but i'm not sure how to change the name meta data.

here is my try but i don't know what to fill in `"entity"` and there is no `oac.setName()`

```
public void renameDirectory(String oldPath, String newName) throws IOException {

    final Storage gsClient = GCSlientFactory.get(PromptoConfig.s.GCP_PROJECT_ID).getGSClient();
    final URI uri = URI.create(oldPath);

    ObjectAccessControl oac = new ObjectAccessControl();
    oac.setId("newName");

    final Storage.ObjectAccessControls.Update update = gsClient.objectAccessControls().update(BUCKET_NAME, uri.toString().replace("gs://"+BUCKET_NAME+"/", ""), "", oac);
    update.execute();
}
```

and also:

```
final Storage gsClient = GCSlientFactory.get(PromptoConfig.s.GCP_PROJECT_ID).getGSClient();
final URI uri = URI.create(oldPath);

ObjectAccessControl oac = new ObjectAccessControl();
oac.set("name", newName);

final Storage.ObjectAccessControls.Update update = gsClient.objectAccessControls().update(BUCKET_NAME, uri.toString().replace("gs://"+BUCKET_NAME+"/", ""), "allUsers", oac);
update.execute();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCS doesn't support true folders -- the namespace is flat, and the meaning of "/" is really imposed by clients (and client libraries). As such, folders can't be renamed atomically - you would need to rename each of the contained files, like what the gsutil mv command does. You can see this by running a command like:

```
gsutil -d mv gs://my-bucket/folder1 gs://my-bucket/folder2
```

The -d option will cause it to output the sequence of requests gsutil generates to do the rename.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for java solution.

Comment: There are Java samples in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#storage-rename-object-java).